# How can I limit the output of a long character in the R console?

Tags: r, character

I'm starting to work on text data. I have a long charachter variable or vector and would like to check either 5 lines or 50 words in my console. How can I limit the output that R show when I inspect a character? Is there a useful R function or setting in RStudio to limit console output?

```
x <- "growth revenue seed fundraise customers spread 50 countries series a funds raised sequoia capital indiasan francisco july 21 2021 prnewswire  multichannel sales engagement platform outplay today announced 73m series a fundraise sequoia capital india outplay funds raised invest technology hiring exceptional talent globethe outplay team celebrating announcement series a fundingbusinesses today rely combination inbound outbound sales models drive revenues while inbound sales process rapidly evolved decade outbound sales  outbound sales teams typically highvolume tactics drive revenue but approach scalable revenue eventually function size outbound sales team this outbound sales teams datadriven approach targeting prospects convert end spending time emailing coldcalling hundreds prospects hoping convert launched 2019 outplay mission change bringing predictability outbound sales sales reps talk prospect time channel the platform helps outbound sales teams plan execute track measure optimize interactions companies prospects multiple channels email phone sms social media live chatlaxman papineni ceo outplay commentedoutbound sales teams dark horse sales organization  targets high methods scientific outplay committed making outbound outreach datadriven sales teams talking warmest prospects point multiple channels optimising time resources the continued partnership sequoia capital india testament fact sales engagement space poised 559b market 2023 huge opportunity outplaywith outplay sales managers create databacked sales playbooks coach team members achieve sales targets the platform combination automation personalization helps teams start genuine conversations scale enabling stay task multiple channels single interface drive meetings sales reps build multichannel outreach plan prospects email phone sms linkedin twitter chatfor  outplay helps sales teams engage warm prospects notifying prospect visits website enabled outplay industry outbound livechat feature rep initiate live chat conversation prospect customers qualify prospects faster grow pipeline 300 tool alongside inbound chatwe continue excited outplay mission making sales rep perform rep team outbound sales evolving rapidly reps personalized automated contextual tools drive sales outplay successfully enabling sales reps spend average hours day outplay demonstrating effectiveness product categoryleading customer reviews additionally rapid digitization due covid significant accelerant business tailwinds continue outbound sales digital  harshjit sethi principal sequoia indiaoutplay offers support ensure software adoption customer teams days weeks months since seed fundraise  usd 2 mn sequoia capital india surge early year company grown 4x revenue 3x team size customers 50 countriesabout outplayoutplay multichannel sales engagement platform ensures outbound sales teams deliver powerful message perfect time buyer journey channel with features dynamic sequencing magic outbound chat detailed analytics outplay sales development representatives sdrs business development representatives bdrs signals work warmest prospects multiple channels email phone sms linkedin twitter chatcontact email protectedlogo photo source outplay"
x
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringr` has `str_trunc` function to do return first `n` characters -

```
stringr::str_trunc(x, 50)
#[1] "growth revenue seed fundraise customers spread ..."
```

For words you may use `word` -

```
stringr::word(x, 1, 50)

#[1] "growth revenue seed fundraise customers spread 50 countries series a funds raised sequoia capital indiasan francisco july 21 2021 prnewswire  multichannel sales engagement platform outplay today announced 73m series a fundraise sequoia capital india outplay funds raised invest technology hiring exceptional talent globethe outplay team celebrating announcement series a"
```

Comment: Okay, that'll do the trick. Is there a built in option in RStudio or is using functions from additional packages the best practice?

Comment: If you do not want to use packages you can use the R base `substr(x, 1, 50)` however if you work a lot with textual data, surely the stringr package will often come in handy!